# Python : How to concatenate dictionaries to create a new ? Dna Center Cisco

Tags: python, dictionary, concatenation

First of all , thanks to read me !

I have an issue regarding my python script , I need to concatenate two dictionnaries payload_1 and payload_2 to payload

```
payload_1 = {'groupName': 'POOL_UNDERLAY-LAN-AUTOMATION',
 'groupOwner': 'DNAC',
 'type': 'generic',
 'siteId': 'ffd0d540-6fee-41d1-ba42-430001cf042f',
 'ipPools': [{'parentUuid': '0b20b02e-341a-4584-9f79-27ed32682efc',
 'dhcpServerIps': ['1.1.1.1',
 '2.2.2.2'],
 'dnsServerIps': ['8.8.8.8'],
 'ipPoolOwner': 'DNAC',
 'shared': 'true',
 'gateways': ['192.168.0.1'],
 'ipPoolCidr': '192.168.0/24'}]}


payload_2 = {'groupName': 'POOL_AP',
 'groupOwner': 'DNAC',
 'type': 'generic',
 'siteId': 'ffd0d540-6fee-41d1-ba42-430001cf042f',
 'ipPools': [{'parentUuid': '0b20b02e-341a-4584-9f79-27ed32682efc',
 'dhcpServerIps': ['1.1.1.1',
 '2.2.2.2'],
 'dnsServerIps': ['8.8.8.8'],
 'ipPoolOwner': 'DNAC',
 'shared': 'true',
 'gateways': ['192.168.1.1'],
 'ipPoolCidr': '192.168.1/24'}]}
```

payload_1 and payload_2 >> are dictionnaries , and need to stay like that.

```
>>> type(payload_1)
<class 'dict'>

>>> type(payload_2)
<class 'dict'>
```

Try :
payload = {**payload_1, **payload_2}

But I have only the last payload_2

```
>>>print(payload)
{'groupName': 'POOL_AP',
 'groupOwner': 'DNAC',
 'type': 'generic',
 'siteId': 'ffd0d540-6fee-41d1-ba42-430001cf042f',
 'ipPools': [{'parentUuid': '0b20b02e-341a-4584-9f79-27ed32682efc',
 'dhcpServerIps': ['1.1.1.1',
 '2.2.2.2'],
 'dnsServerIps': ['8.8.8.8'],
 'ipPoolOwner': 'DNAC',
 'shared': 'true',
 'gateways': ['192.168.1.1'],
 'ipPoolCidr': '192.168.1/24'}]}
```

If fact , I'm waiting this result :  payload_1,payload2

```
{'groupName': 'POOL_UNDERLAY-LAN-AUTOMATION',
 'groupOwner': 'DNAC',
 'type': 'generic',
 'siteId': 'ffd0d540-6fee-41d1-ba42-430001cf042f',
 'ipPools': [{'parentUuid': '0b20b02e-341a-4584-9f79-27ed32682efc',
 'dhcpServerIps': ['1.1.1.1',
 '2.2.2.2'],
 'dnsServerIps': ['8.8.8.8'],
 'ipPoolOwner': 'DNAC',
 'shared': 'true',
 'gateways': ['192.168.0.1'],
 'ipPoolCidr': '192.168.0/24'}]}
{'groupName': 'POOL_AP',
 'groupOwner': 'DNAC',
 'type': 'generic',
 'siteId': 'ffd0d540-6fee-41d1-ba42-430001cf042f',
 'ipPools': [{'parentUuid': '0b20b02e-341a-4584-9f79-27ed32682efc',
 'dhcpServerIps': ['1.1.1.1',
 '2.2.2.2'],
 'dnsServerIps': ['8.8.8.8'],
 'ipPoolOwner': 'DNAC',
 'shared': 'true',
 'gateways': ['192.168.1.1'],
 'ipPoolCidr': '192.168.1/24'}]}
```

How can I do that ?

I try to use command like this :

payload = json.dumps(payload_1) + json.dumps(payload_2)

It's Works but payload is now a string !!

```
>>> type(payload)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

It's not good for me !

Could you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona

Comment: No , unfortunately . I already try :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually the result you want like `payload_1,payload2` is not ONE data structure.

Maybe what you need is list, like

```
>>> payload = [payload_1, payload_2]
>>> type(payload)
<class 'list'>
```

Or if you really need a dict, you need to know a dict must has both key and value. Like this:

```
>>> payload = {'payload_1': payload_1, 'payload_2': payload_2}
>>> type(payload)
<class 'dict'>
```